# When I have a matching glue code eclipse throws the following error - Step 'User is already on loginpage' does not have a matching glue code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm unable to run my runner file in eclipse as eclipse says Step -'User is already on loginpage' does not have a matching glue code on my feature file.

Also when I close and open the feature file eclipse says- An internal error occurred during: "Scanning for step definitions".
    java.lang.NullPointerException

When I run the runner file Ecipse shows the below error

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

```
@Given("^User is already on loginpage$")
public void user_is_already_on_loginpage() throws Throwable {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  throw new PendingException();
} .....
```

I have tried specifying the path to my feature file and step definition file in so many different ways, but nothing has worked.

Feature file

> Feature: Free CRM login feature
>
> Scenario: CRM login
>
> Given User is already on loginpage
>
> When title of login pageis free CRM
>
> Then user enters user name an d password
>
> Then user clicks on login button
>
> Then user is on homepage

Step Definition File

```
    package stepDefinitions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;

    import cucumber.api.java.en.*;
    import org.junit.Assert;


    public class LogInStepDefinition {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Given("^User is already on loginpage$")

    public void User_is_already_on_loginpage() {
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
        "C://chromedriver.exe");
        driver.get("http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login");
    }

    @When("^title of login pageis free CRM$")

    public void title_ofloginpage_is_free_CRM() {
        String ActualTitle=driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals("Web Scraper Testing Ground", ActualTitle);
    }

    @Then("^user enters user name an d password$")
    public void user_enters_user_name_and_password()  {

    driver.findElement(By.id("usr")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("12345");
    }


    @Then("^user clicks on login button$")
    public void user_clicks_on_login_button()  {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='case_login']/form/input[3]")).click();
    }

    @Then("^user is on homepage$")
    public void user_is_on_homepage()  {

        String pageVeri=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[@id='case_login']/h3[@class='success']")).getText();    
        Assert.assertEquals("WELCOME :)", pageVeri);;
    }   
    }
```

```
Runner file
```

```
    package Runner;

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)

    @CucumberOptions(
    features="src/main/java/Features/login.feature",
    glue= {"/src/main/java/stepDefinitions/LogInStepDefinition.java"}
    //format= {"pretty","html:test-output"}
    )

    public class TestRunner {

    }
```

POM.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>FreeCRMBDDFramework</groupId>
    <artifactId>FreeCRMBDDFramework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>FreeCRMBDDFramework</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>





    <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer 
    -->

    <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Comment: I have seen people keep feature files under src test resources but I see you giving path as src main Java. Are you really saving feature file under src main java

Comment: Yes, my step definition file, feature file and runner file , all are under src main java. Does it really matter where I save the files? And the way I have given the path in my runner file, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your glue code, remove the "/" before `"src"`. Due to this, runner can't find your step definition file.

Changes should be: `glue={"src/main/java/stepDefinitions/LogInStepDefinition.java"}`

And for the issue: "Scanning for step definitions". java.lang.NullPointerException.

In the LogInStepDefinition.java file, add these individual imports:

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
```

Instead of:

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.*;
```

Once changed as above, close and reopen the feature file in eclipse.